# How can I make my program compile without warning?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation, compiler-warnings

I should compile my program with spec flags to gcc. Then gcc complained about return values not taken care of. WhenI use variables to take the return values then gcc complains again:

```
$ gcc -pedantic -Wall -ansi -O4 miniShell.c
miniShell.c: In function ‘cd’:
miniShell.c:108:9: warning: variable ‘other_return’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int other_return;
         ^
miniShell.c:107:12: warning: variable ‘return_value’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     char * return_value;
            ^
```

How can I resolve the warnings? My program is as follows.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFFER_LEN 1024
#define BUFFERSIZE 1024


int mystrcmp(char const *, char const *);


void err_syserr(char *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errnum != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "(%d: %s)\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int main() {
    char line[BUFFER_LEN];  
    char* argv[100];        
    char* path= "/bin/";    
    char progpath[20];      
    int argc;               
    size_t length;
    char *token;
    int i=0;
    int pid;
    while(1) {
    i = 0;
        printf("miniShell>> ");                    

        if(!fgets(line, BUFFER_LEN, stdin)) { 
            break;                                
        }
        length = strlen(line);
        if (line[length - 1] == '\n') {
            line[length - 1] = '\0';
        }
        if(strcmp(line, "exit")==0) {           
            break;
        }


        token = strtok(line," ");

        while(token!=NULL) {
            argv[i]=token;
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
            i++;
        }
        argv[i]=NULL;                     

        argc=i;                           
        for(i=0; i<argc; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", argv[i]);      
        }
        strcpy(progpath, path);           
        strcat(progpath, argv[0]);            

        for(i=0; i<strlen(progpath); i++) {   
            if(progpath[i]=='\n') {
                progpath[i]='\0';
            }
        }
        pid= fork();              

        if(pid==0) {              
            execvp(progpath,argv);
            fprintf(stderr, "Child process could not do execvp\n");

        } else {                  
            wait(NULL);
            printf("Child exited\n");
        }

    }
return (0);
}

int mystrcmp(char const *p, char const *q)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; q[i]; i++)
    {
        if(p[i] != q[i])
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int cd(char *pth) {
    char path[BUFFERSIZE];
    char cwd[BUFFERSIZE];
    char * return_value;
    int other_return;
    strcpy(path,pth);

    if(pth[0] != '/')
    {  
        return_value = getcwd(cwd,sizeof(cwd));
        strcat(cwd,"/");
        strcat(cwd,path);
        other_return = chdir(cwd);
    } else { 
        other_return = chdir(pth);
    }
    printf("Spawned foreground process: %d\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either you use those variables, or you remove them.

Comment: @Mat I have no use for the variables but they are there to not get warning since gcc complains if I omit a variable for the return value. I don't know on option that won't generate a warning.

Comment: Well, use them then. The functions you're calling can fail. Check for failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I guess the original problem you were trying to solve was a warning along the lines of:

```
 warning: ignoring return value of ‘chdir’
```

And you've tried to fix that by assigning the return value to a variable (which itself is now unused).

`getcwd` and `chdir` can both return error codes if they fail, which are the return values GCC is warning you about. If you want to fix the warning properly you should add logic to your code to detect and handle these error cases. Otherwise, you are potentially continuing with a state inconsistent with your assumptions (for example, you may be in an unexpected directory if `getcwd` failed and left your buffer in an incorrectly initialised state).

I had thought that this could be over-ridden by casting the result of the function call to void, but this does not work (you can still play tricks, but they get messy!). The GCC documentation for the `warn_unused_result` attribute says:

> The warn_unused_result attribute causes a warning to be emitted if a
>   caller of the function with this attribute does not use its return
>   value. This is useful for functions where not checking the result is
>   either a security problem or always a bug,

Which suggests that you don't want to find a workaround for the warning, and should really be checking the return value for error conditions.

If you really want to do it, assign the result to a variable as you have done, then add a single use of that variable, cast to void:

```
int res = chdir (cwd);
/* I promise I don't need to check this return value.  */
(void) res;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 2 things wrong here in your code. The first one probably caused you to change your code, which then caused the warning you are now asking about.

I bet you the first initial warning was about `chdir`. As the documents say:

> man chdir(3): "Upon successful completion, 0 shall be returned. 
>                  Otherwise, -1 shall be returned, the current working 
>                  directory shall remain unchanged, and errno shall be set to 
>                  indicate the error."

As it says, `chdir` can return an error code stating if anything went wrong and the first initial warning was caused due to the fact you simply ignored that value.

Then you changed your code and assigned the value to another variable and got:

> warning: variable ‘other_return’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
>    int other_return;

and you can see in this function that you are only setting a value to that variable but don't actually use it later which means you can delete it:

```
int cd(char *pth) {
char path[BUFFERSIZE];
char cwd[BUFFERSIZE];
char * return_value;
int other_return;
strcpy(path,pth);

if(pth[0] != '/')
{  
    return_value = getcwd(cwd,sizeof(cwd));
    strcat(cwd,"/");
    strcat(cwd,path);
    other_return = chdir(cwd);
} else { 
    other_return = chdir(pth);
}
printf("Spawned foreground process: %d\n", getpid());
return 0;
}
```

Same thing for `return_value`. You can simply delete them both since they are not in use.

In case you want to avoid the first initial warnings you can always do something like this:

```
int res = chdir (cwd);
(void) res;
```

This is an assurance made by you to the compiler that everything is fine and he can ignore the warning.

Comment: `man chdir(3)`: "Upon successful completion, 0 shall be returned. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned, the current working directory shall remain unchanged, and errno shall be set to indicate the error."

Answer (score 1):

The other users have answered how you can get rid of the warning by fixing your code, but just for reference: If you want to 'ignore' the warnings, compile with the flag:

```
-Wno-unused-but-set-variable
```

The compiler usually gives you a tag at the end of a warning (in your case, it's -Wunused-but-set-variable). To ignore it, just change the -W to a -Wno-

Hope this helps!